# Get final elements of nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How do I get the latest elements of the nested dictionary by one or few keys?

For example my nested dict is:

```
{
'key_1' : 
        {
         'key_1_1' : 
                    {
                     'key_1_1_1' : 
                                  value1, value2
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                     'key_1_1_2' : 
                                  value3
                    }
         }

} 

>>>dict[key_1]
value1, value2, value3
>>>dict[key_1][key_1_1][key_1_1_2]
value3
```

Comment: what kind of data do you have as values? `value1, value2` is not valid python

Comment: it is for example, the values is list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple recursive function should do what you're looking for:

```
def vals(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        result = []
        for v in x.values():
            result.extend(vals(v))
        return result
    else:
        return [x]
```

used as..

```
>>> d = {1:2, 3:{4:5, 6:7}}
>>> vals(d)
[2, 5, 7]
>>> vals(d[1])
[2]
>>> vals(d[3])                                                                  
[5, 7]
```