# Reduce nested dictionary to "top-key-root-element" dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to derive a dictionary from a nested dictionary with the top keys as keys and the root elements as values. This post is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755828/get-final-elements-of-nested-dictionary-in-python), but I would like to end up with a dictionary not with a list of lists.

Example: How to get from this

```
d = {'foo':{'a':{'b':['1','2']}},
     'bar':{'a':{'b':{'c':'3'}}}}
```

to this?

`{'foo': ['1', '2'], 'bar': '3'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'foo':{'a':{'b':['1','2']}},
     'bar':{'c':{'d':'3'}}}

def get_last_value(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            return get_last_value(v)
    return d

result = {k:get_last_value(v) for k, v in d.items()}

print(result)
```

result:

```
{'foo': ['1', '2'], 'bar': '3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'foo':{'a':{'b':['1','2']}},
     'bar':{'c':{'d':'3'}}}

for key, value, in d.items():
    print(key, value.values())
```